# SQL Server Always Encrypted connectionString ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, cryptoapi, always-encrypted

Always Encrypted uses a certificate in the Windows Certificate Store to decrypt data from SQL Server. This certificate is protected by the Microsoft CryptoAPI private key using a password.

What is the best practice to use that password in the connection string?

The connection string without the password is as follows:

```
Data Source=<ip,port>;Initial Catalog=@@@@@@;Column Encryption Setting = Enabled;Persist Security Info=false;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;User ID=@@@@;Password=@@@@@@@@
```

When using this in Visual Studio 2019, it pops up a dialog that asks for password.

Comment: I’m not entirely certain if it will matter, but for clarity: What edition and version of ASP.NET are you running on? Where are you storing your connection string? Those may be useful details to factor in.